# How to install the npm command on the linux

Tags: node.js, linux, npm, npm-install

I'm trying to install the `npm ci` command on **Linux**. It's not working. Showing the following prompt. Could anyone help me with this?

````
ubuntu@ip-172-31-25-55:~/aws$ npm cl

Usage: npm <command>

where <command> is one of:
    access, add-user, adduser, apihelp, author, bin, bugs, c,
    cache, completion, config, ddp, dedupe, deprecate, dist-tag,
    dist-tags, docs, edit, explore, faq, find, find-dupes, get,
    help, help-search, home, i, info, init, install,
    install-test, issues, it, la, link, list, ll, ln, login,
    logout, ls, outdated, owner, pack, ping, prefix, prune,
    publish, r, rb, rebuild, remove, repo, restart, rm, root,
    run-script, s, se, search, set, show, shrinkwrap, star,
    stars, start, stop, t, tag, team, test, tst, un, uninstall,
    unlink, unpublish, unstar, up, update, upgrade, v, verison,
    version, view, whoami

npm <cmd> -h     quick help on <cmd>
npm -l           display full usage info
npm faq          commonly asked questions
npm help <term>  search for help on <term>
npm help npm     involved overview

Specify configs in the ini-formatted file:
    /home/ubuntu/.npmrc
or on the command line via: npm <command> --key value
Config info can be viewed via: npm help config

npm@3.5.2 /usr/share/npm```
````

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Comment: Hi Kevin, I'm new to write questions on Stackoverflow. Appreciate your advice

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to install NPM with running these commands.

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | sudo -E bash -
```

Then:

```
sudo apt install nodejs
```

Check to see if it is installed:

```
node --version
```

If it outputs a version number, you are good!